Importance of orthogonality in Minkowski space
I am currently studying Minkowski space. Orthogonality in this space is new to me. I have seen in a blog post, in 1 that states that, orthogonality is important in this space.
It will be helpful, if anyone can suggest to me references where I can find more about  orthogonality.
Reference:
[1] https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/orthogonality-in-minkowski-spacetime-meaning-visualization.1016318/#:~:text=1.,in%20a%20four%2Ddimensional%20spacetime.

in a vector space with a symmetric bilinear form $g$, two vectors $x$ and $y$ are said to be orthogonal if we have $g(x,y) = 0$. In Minkowski space, every lightlike vector is orthogonal to itself, and every timelike vector is orthogonal to a spacelike one. Every introductory textbook on special relativity covers these topics.

Do you see why it's convenient to choose orthogonal frames for navigating ordinary 3-space, or ordinary 2-space?

So if you have two four vectors:
$$a_{\mu} = (a_0, \vec a) $$
$$b_{\mu} = (b_0, \vec a) $$
their inner product is:
$$ a^{\mu}b_{\mu} =  a_0b_0 - \vec a \cdot \vec b $$
and what makes that important is that it is a Lorentz scalar, that is, it is an invariant in all inertial frames.
What makes that useful, is that you can solve it in a simple frame, and use it elsewhere.
For instance, if they are the coordinates of two events:
$$ E^{\mu}_a = (ct_a, \vec r_a) $$
$$ E^{\mu}_b = (ct_b, \vec r_b) $$
we can take the inner product of their difference with itself and get:
$$ (E^{\mu}_b-E^{\mu}_a)^2 = \big(c^2(t_b-t_a)^2 -(\vec r_b-\vec r_a)^2\big)\equiv \Delta s^2$$
which is the Lorentz invariant interval (squared). Regarding orthogonality, if $ \Delta s^2 = 0 $, then the events are light-like separated. They lie on the light-cones of all inertial frames.
The sign determines if vectors are time-like or space-like separated, also invariant in all frames.
Now if one vector lies on the time (and a space) axis:
$$ a_{\mu} = (ct_a, 0,0,0) $$
$$ b_{\mu} = (0, \vec b)$$
then
$$ a^{\mu}b_{\mu} = 0 $$
and for any boost along $\vec b$, $a'_{\mu}$ and $b'_{\mu}$ can describe the time axis and a spatial axis (I'm not worrying about rotating $\vec b$). [N.B: this differs from @paulina's comment, which is too general, as time-like and space-like can overlap. There may be a name for 4-vectors that have finite time (space) and zero space (time) components, but idk what it is].
Now a really useful case is: Consider a photon defined by it's 4-wave vector:
$$ k_{\mu} = (k, 0, 0, k) $$
reflecting,
$$ k'_{\mu} = (k', 0, 0, -k') $$
off a massive mirror at rest:
$$ u_{\mu} = M(c, 0, 0, 0) $$
The momentum transfer from the photon to the mirror is
$$q_{\mu} = \hbar(k_{\mu} - k'_{\mu}) = \hbar(k-k', 0, 0, k+k') $$
bouncing off a massive mirror at rest:
$$u_{\mu} = (c, 0, 0, 0) $$
That 4-momentum transfer has to be orthogonal to the 4-velocity to ensure that:
$$ |p'_{\mu}|^2 = |Mu'_{\mu}|^2 = E'^2 - |\vec p'|^2 = M^2c^2 $$
So in this simple frame:
$$ q^{\mu}u_{\mu} = \hbar c(k'-k) = 0 $$
so that:
$$ k' = -k $$
$$ \vec k' = -\vec k $$
So what? That is just reflection, the light does a 180 and is the same frequency.
Ok, now boost that by $v$ along $\hat z$:
$$ Mu_{\mu} = M\gamma(c, 0, 0, v) $$
and set:
$$ q^{\mu}u_{\mu} = 0$$
and solve for $k'_{\mu}$.
I don't have time to do it right now, but you should be able to derive the relativistic Doppler shift (squared):
$$ f_D^2 = \frac{1-v/c}{1+v/c}$$
So we can take a simple intuitive situation: reflection, and turn it in to the Doppler shift all from orthogonally being a Lorentz invariant. No need to think about phase fronts and time dilated frequencies...Kinda powerful.

how can timelike and spacelike overlap? as far as I understand, they are disjoint subsets of the spacetime, with the light cone as a common boundary.

@paulina I set what you're saying, but $(5, 4)(3, 4) = 15-16=-1 \ne 0 $, so idk?

I said that every timelike vector is orthogonal to a spacelike one. In your example, that would be $(4,5)$. Of course you can find vectors that are not orthogonal.

@paulina yup. I should stop posting during Teams meetings. But the question is now closed (?) so it's all in the rearview.
